# Codename One Control Center not working on Linux OS (Ubuntu)

Tags: codenameone

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA on my machine but I can't open CN1 Control Center application. Nothing happened when I click on `Codename One Preferences`.

I already ran `java -jar ~/.codenameone/UpdateCodenameOne.jar PATH_TO_PROJECT` which updated my libraries.

I'm able to launch the Control Center from Command-Line, using `guibuilder.jar`:

```
java  -jar ~/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar -settings PATH_TO_PROJECT/codenameone_settings.properties
```

Similarly, clicking a `theme.res` file doesn't launch the old GUI Builder straightway. I have to first open `Codename One Designer` from Codename One options, then open the `theme.res` from the old GUI Builder.

What can I do to easily access these GUI applications?

I'm running the following JVM is:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I also tried:

```
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

The command IntelliJ tried to run is:

```
/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/326/jbr/bin/java # custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -jar ~/.codenameone/guibuilder.jar -settings PROJECT_PATH/codenameone_settings.properties
```

And this is my [IDEA.log](https://pastebin.com/XWwsG49b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running with the plugin and trying to launch with the plugin and not via the maven action which resolves this problem.

For this to work with the plugin you need to update the project which you can do in one of two ways:

- Use the following command:  `java -jar ~/.codenameone/UpdateCodenameOne.jar PATH_TO_PROJECT`
- Launch from command line once by running with the ZuluFX VM

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to launch "Codename One Preferences" with the plugin. Running the above command doesn't update anything as it seems the project is up-to-date; ```CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=183
CodenameOne_SRCzip=196
CodenameOneJar=196
JavaSEJar=196
CLDC11Jar=163```

I still can't launch the Preferences UI after updating the project.

Comment: Did you try launching the UI from command line? With different VMs you have in the system? All the jars are in `.codenameone`.

Comment: Which jar specifically launches the Control Center?

Comment: Ok, I see that `guibuilder.jar` is used for the Control Center. I'm able to launch this from command line but couldn't properly launch it with the necessary elements and parameters.

Comment: Can you clarify what didn't work for you by editing the question?
Can you include the arguments you used and can you try other JVMs installed in your system to see what might have failed?

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: If you try running the intellij command yourself does that work? If not what part of the command is the failure? Is it one of the arguments on the JVM itself? What's the error message?

Comment: Running the command failed with wrong arguments, but was successful when I removed this `# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options`

Comment: This prompted me to go to "Help -> Edit Custom VM Options..." in IntelliJ and remove `# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options`, then I was able to launch Control Center from the `Codename One Preferences` dropdown option. I was also able to launch the old GUI Builder normally by double-clicking `theme.res`.

Comment: Great job. I wonder how many of those issues were caused by this...